# Git: how to roll back to last push/commit

Tags: git, version-control

I am programming.  I add beautiful code and commit and push it to my repo like:

```
git add *
git commit
//writes message
git push unfuddle master
```

Now i go in and screw everything up.  I have not issued a git command since I push the beauty.  How do i make my local files go back to what was committed?

`git pull` says my local repo is "up to date"

`git checkout` spams out my screen and doesnt  seem to change anything.

To be clear: I am not trying to modify my remote repo, just get my local repo to look like the server.

My current solution is to delete the folder and reclone the repo.  That can't be right.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can reset to HEAD: `git reset --hard HEAD`

Comment: `git stash` I have found also does what I want.

Comment: sure, you can also use your last hard drive backup to get there :)

Answer (score 23):

UPDATE:

The best way to do this is to

```
git stash -u
```

Do not

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

it is an operation that cannot be undone and you can truly nuke your work unless you're using time machine on a Mac or the new backup service on Windows 8. Linux may have a scheme like that although I don't use one.

If you also want ignored files nuked, you can

```
git clean -xdf
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you haven't committed anything yet, the following command will reset your modified files:

```
git checkout .
```

Answer (score 3):

> git pull says my local repo is "up to date"

`git pull` is telling you your repository is up to date because your local repository and your remote repository both point to the same HEAD (the last commit). This is due to your `git push`, which synced the *remote* with your *local* repository.

Git doesn't compare the changes that haven't been committed to the remote branch when it decides what to pull; thus, from Gits point of view, your *local* and *remote* repositories are at the same point in time, even though your *local* repository has unstaged changes (changes that you have not `git add`ed).

There's a nice diagram on the bottom of [this page](http://progit.org/book/ch1-3.html) which shows you how the process works - you make some changes, stage them (by running `git add`), and then finally commit them to the repository (through the creatively named `git commit`).

> To be clear: I am not trying to modify my remote repo, just get my local repo to look like the server.

Others have pointed out the methods to do this: 
`git reset --hard HEAD` (reset the index [staged files] and the working tree [unstaged files] to the last commit), but it's worth having an understanding of what you're trying to achieve - if I'd known *how* git was tracking my files the first time I messed up my working tree, I'd have saved hours of fretting.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
git stash
git pull origin your-branch
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `git checkout -f master`?

Answer (score 1):

If you does not have committed anything, you can simply do a `$ git reset --hard`. If you have committed some stuff, you can do a `git reset --hard origin/master` to go back to the version that is on the remote.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout branchname
 git reset --hard c4e0424
 git push origin +branchname`

You can use --soft instead of --hard
`--hard` you will LOSE your changes
`--soft` leave your changed files of commit